# Use wifi direct via bridge on ethernet enabled devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, wireless-bridge

i have sony smart tv which supports wifi-direct and has ethernet port on it.
I have a wifi bridge or wifi router which is connected to my tv using Ethernet port rather than those sony wifi-adapetr.
Now i want to connect my smart phone with tv using wifi-direct feature is this possible?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you do this? Why not just connect your smart phone to your wifi bridge or wifi router?

Comment: I am ready to connect but will i be able to share content with my TV as we can with WIFI direct?

Comment: So you're not trying to get Internet access? You're trying to set up a purely private network between your phone and your TV?

Comment: I can get internet access on my tv as i have other router with my isp connected to it and connect it to bridge wireless...but at some time also want a private network too